# jQuery UI - which CSS to include?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s documentation can be quite confusing when it comes to what CSS you actually need and I saw some people rather include just all.

So if I've download jQuery UI:

1. what CSS do I need to include?
2. which one's which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including all the CSS will work, but it is the **wrong** approach...

This answer relates to current last stable release of jQuery UI: 1.11.4.

## What CSS you need

It depends on how you want to structure/split your CSS logic and whether you want to use 
full-package or just some parts.

### Using full-package

#### One CSS only:

Just include production version of `jquery-ui` CSS

## QUICK ANSWER: **`jquery-ui.min.css`**

This file contains both:

 - structure(for jQuery UI to work properly)

 - theme CSS (for jQuery UI to look better :) ).

#### Separate structure & style

**DON'T INCLUDE `jquery-ui` CSS!**

Include separate (production) file for structure and for theme e.g.:

**`jquery-ui.structure.min.css`** and **`jquery-ui.theme.min.css`** **- in this order!**

If you don't want to include theme at all, just include production version of `jquery-ui.structure`...

---

### Using only some parts

If you worry about the performance/loading you've probably chose only some parts of jQuery UI, most probably, you could have done it in one of these ways...

#### Download Builder

If you've prepared your jQuery UI files through the [Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) the instructions are the same as for **Using full-package** (see above).

#### Core & Components

If you've downloaded core and components, first include production version of the core CSS, e.g.:

**`core.min.css`**

Then include other CSS in an **order** that **dependencies are before those that depend** on them.

As **last**, include theme's production CSS.